# Extend Bound after direction service google map api v3

Tags: google-maps

I used markers as well as direction service in my map.

I used  bounds.extend(lat),map.fitBounds(bounds);to extend the maps to show all my markers. This was working fine until i used direction service. once the direction is used, map automatically zooms to the direction from A to B.Only two markers pointing A and B are visible now in map.

But i want the map to show all the markers with the direction used between two other markers.

How could i do it?

```
Issue solved by using the following line
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            preserveViewport:true
        });
```

Comment: Provide some related code, that we could work on it.

Comment: Provided my code, sorry for the ugly code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the directionsRenderer to zoom to its results, use the [preserveViewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) option.

Another option would be to use the [union](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) of the bounds of the route returned by the directionsService and the bounds you calculated for your markers.